# CSS several <p> in one inline

Tags: html

[image]

As you see, I'm trying to put two `<p>` in one line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your container probably isn't wide enough to display them side-by-side.

Comment: For future reference, it would be better to include all relevant code in your question, rather than a screenshot of it - otherwise any attempts to solve your problem will at best rely heavily on (educated) guesswork.

Comment: Do you have to use `<p>`? I think `<span>` would be better for this situation. `<p>` is meant for paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look for the width of the div you putting the two P's if the width of the div is less than the width of the two text then the second P will automatically move to next line if div size large then you apply float property of css on div  with position relative

Answer (score 2):

Make the container bigger. Or the font smaller so it fits in one line.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>`s are, by default, block elements, so they aren't normally displayed inline.

To fix this, you have to add `display:inline;` to the `style` tag in each of your `<p>`s.

If this still doesn't work, that means that the containing `<div>` isn't wide enough for both of them to be side by side.
Which means that you have to increase the width of the `<div>`.